# is fread on a single integer affected by the endianness of my system

Tags: c, file, endianness

I'm currently working on a binary file format for some arbitrary values, including some strings, and string-length values, which are stored as `uint32_t`'s.

But I was wondering, if I write the string length with `fwrite` to a file on a little-endian system, and read that value from the same file with `fread` on a big-endian system, will the oder of the bytes be reversed? And if so, what is the best practice to fix that?

EDIT: Surely there has to be some GNU functionality around that does this for me, and that is used, tested and validated for, like, 20 years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `fwrite` and `fread` on an integer makes your file format unportable to another endianness, as other answers correctly state.

As of best practice, I would *discourage any conditional byte flipping and endianness testing at all*. Decide on the endianness of your *file format*, than write and read *bytes*, and make integers from them by ORing and shifting.

In other words, [I agree with Rob Pike](http://commandcenter.blogspot.ru/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) on the issue.

Answer (score 3):

> If I write the string length with fwrite to a file on a little-endian system, and read that value from the same file with fread on a big-endian system, will the oder of the bytes be reversed?

Yes.  `fwrite` simply writes the memory contents to file in linear order.  `fread` simply reads from file to memory in linear order.

> What is the best practice to fix that?

Decide on an ordering for your files.  Then write wrapper functions to write and read integers to/from files.  Inside this function, conditionally flip the byte order if you're on a system with the opposite ordering.

(There are [lots of questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+determine+endianness) regarding determining the endianness of a system.)

> Surely there has to be some GNU functionality around that does this for me

There's nothing in the standard library.  However, POSIX defines a bunch of functions for this: [`ntohl`, `htonl`, etc.](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl).  They're typically used for network transfer, but could equally be used for files.

Comment: surely there's something available that abstracts this hell away from my code?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin There is, see my answer.

Comment: allright, thanks. Another quick search brought up `man 3 endian` which should help me out. Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will, since `fread()` operates on <s>war</s> raw bytes. If the order of bytes is different in memory, it will be different in the file too.

> And if so, what is the best practice to fix that?

Detect the endianness of your system, and flip the bytes if it doesn't match the endianness of your file format.

```
int is_little_endian()
{
    uint32_t magic = 0x00000001;
    uint8_t black_magic = *(uint8_t *)&magic;
    return black_magic;
}

uint32_t to_little_endian(uint32_t dword)
{
    if (is_little_endian()) return dword;

    return (((dword >>  0) & 0xff) << 24)
         | (((dword >>  8) & 0xff) << 16)
         | (((dword >> 16) & 0xff) <<  8)
         | (((dword >> 24) & 0xff) <<  0);
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `&` in your endian detection function.

Comment: I think I prefer the glibc provided funcitons over a homebrew solution. Still, I appreciate the effort :) Thanks!

Comment: @CarlNorum True. That's why I should have written it locally first and paste only after compiling.

Comment: Use bit shifts instead, then you don't have to worry about the endianness of your machine

Answer (score 1):

Linux provides

htobe16, htole16, be16toh, le16toh, htobe32, htole32, be32toh, le32toh, htobe64, htole64, be64toh, le64toh - convert values between host and big-/little-endian byte order

[https://linux.die.net/man/3/le32toh]